# How to populate 2 combobox in DevExpress grid?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress

I am developing a website in which I am using DevExpress controls. I need to add a row using AddNewRow event of the grid. Everything is working fine i.e the data is being saved in the database. But now I need to have 2 comboboxes in the grid itself. One should be populated automatically when we need to add a new row and the second should be populated on the selectedIndexChanged of the first combobox.
The second combobox shold be populated using the selected value of first combobox. 
How can i populate the second combobox.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Cascading Combo Boxes](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/CascadingComboBoxes.aspx) demo. I believe that demonstrates exactly what you needed.

Related example:
[How to implement cascaded combo box columns in ASPxGridView without using templates.](https://www.devexpress.dev/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E3689&ShowHidden=True)